# Arrange imageview in the middle of top layout

Tags: android, positioning, android-relativelayout

I have a layout like this with a custom top header. I want the `ImageView` to be in the middle of the header, ie, center_horizontal. I tried with setting the layout gravity and gravity for the layouts but it sometimes is okay. But when I tried the app in landscape mode, the logo went to one side and the image is not at correct center of the layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/phoneoptLayout"
android:background="@mipmap/bgg"
android:paddingBottom="5dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="5dp"
android:paddingRight="6dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/top"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_back" />

    <ImageView android:src="@mipmap/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And in another layout I have an exit button on the right of the header. This is also not at the center. I am new to android so I do not know what will correct this.

Comment: I think your tag start with RelativeLayout and end with Linearlayout. What is actually use have to use?

Comment: Can you add the screenshot for the page in landscape.

Answer (score 1):

I Hope this will work for you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/phoneoptLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="6dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It is still the same in landscape view. :/

Answer (score 0):

Replace your linear layout with relative layout. Also you have top Relative layout but you have closed linear layout.

Answer (score 0):

you have used `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` in your LinearLayout. you will get your LinearLayout in middle of top layout.

***For example :***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/phoneoptLayout"
    android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="6dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/top"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/back"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/send_video" />

        <ImageView android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

do your linearlayout width "match_parent"
like this

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/top"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the LinearLayout's height and width to match parent and gravity center

```
    <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/top"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:layout_gravity="center">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the below code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/phoneoptLayout"
android:background="@mipmap/bgg">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/back"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_back" />

        <ImageView 
            android:src="@mipmap/logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```